# Multiple lists using for loop with some condition in Python/PySpark

Tags: python, for-loop, pyspark, dynamic-programming

```
All_Items = ['RWr', 'CO', 'UP1', 'EN1', 'Comm']
```

**clpd_rdm** is pyspark dataframe having column 'Metric' and 'Spp_value' in it along with other columns.

Want to create list of each individual item from above list with condition like this:

```
RWr_Base = list(clpd_rdm.filter(clpd_rdm.Metric == 'Rwr').select("Spp_value").distinct().toPandas()['Spp_value'])

CO_Base = list(clpd_rdm.filter(clpd_rdm.Metric == 'CO').select("Spp_value").distinct().toPandas()['Spp_value'])

UP1_Base = list(clpd_rdm.filter(clpd_rdm.Metric == 'UP1').select("Spp_value").distinct().toPandas()['Spp_value'])

EN1_Base = list(clpd_rdm.filter(clpd_rdm.Metric == 'EN1').select("Spp_value").distinct().toPandas()['Spp_value'])
```

All these above individual lists worked as expected but when tried to create these lists dynamicaally using for loop, got error saying "Cannot assign to operator"

Tried this:

```
for n in range(len(All_Items)):
    All_Items[n]+'_Base' = list(clpd_rdm.filter(clpd_rdm.Metric == All_Items[n]).select("Spp_value").distinct().toPandas()['Spp_value'])
```

Please suggest any other way of creating these kind of list dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Try use a dict and store the lists as values

```
All_Items = ['RWr', 'CO', 'UP1', 'EN1', 'Comm']
lists = {}
for ind in range(len(All_Items)):
    lists[All_Items[ind] + '_base'] = list(...)
```

Then you can access each list using the key:

```
 lists = {'RWr_base': [...],
     'CO_base': [...],
     'UP1_base': [...],
     'EN1_base': [...],
     'Comm_base': [...]}
```